# Using result of one function to call other in bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I am working on nodejs and converting my model callbacks to promises as much as possible by keeping response data same to controller so that I don’t need to change controller logic.So I need to use callbacks which I know is a bad idea while working with bluebird.

```
 var functions={ 
              checkifexists:function(data){
              return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                // Query is fired here  
                resolve(data) or reject (data) 
              }); 
            },
             create:function(data,cb{
              mysql.getConnectionFromPool(function(err,connection){
              this.checkifexists(data,connection).then(function(res){
                if(res.count)
                 {
                    cb(res.count);
                }
                else
                {
                    connection.query(insertsql,data,function(err,data){
                         // Handle any error or return insertID
                           cb(null,insertID)
                    });
                }
            }).catch(function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }).finally(function(){
                connection.release();
            });
        });}
```

Based on accepted answer Sample Controller Code:

```
 sampleModel.create(req.body,function(err,result){
    console.log("Err : "+err); // Always Null
    console.log("Result :"+result); // Always displays both reject and resolve cases
});
```

In above code there is one checkifexists function and a create function but from controller only create function is called so I adjusted by code accordingly but still it looks messy.

Is it the right way to do it ? What if I need to call series of function but one after another so that I may pass response of one function to another and so on .

Comment: "*I need to use callbacks*" - sorry, I didn't get the reason for that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You should promisify `connection.query` as well

Comment: Actually  the code has been breakdown into controllers and models so currently I just want to change model to promises not controller part which has callbacks implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dealing manually with callbacks you should use [`asCallback`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html). Promisify your node-style connection things, and use promises wherever you can.

```
var functions = {
    getConnection: function() {
        return Promise.fromCallback(mysql.getConnectionFromPool.bind(mysql))
        .disposer(function(connection) {
            connection.release();
        });
    },
    checkifexists: function(data, connection) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            // Query is fired here  
            resolve(data) or reject (data) 
        }); 
    },
    insert: function(data, connection) {
        return Promise.fromCallback(connection.query.bind(connection, insertsql, data));
    },
    create: function(data, cb) {
        return Promise.using(this.getConnection(), function(connection) {
            return this.checkifexists(data, connection)
            .then(function(res) {
                if (res.count) {
                    throw res.count; // are you sure?
                } else {
                    return this.insert(data, connection);
                }
            }.bind(this))
        }.bind(this))
        .asCallback(cb); // this is all you need
    });
};
```

Comment: your answer just worked perfectly but I didn't understand one thing how is mysql connection error handled automatically with your code if getConnectionFromPool()  has either  cb(null,connection) or cb(err)

Comment: @Vibhas `fromCallback` does that for you so you don't need to write it out every time

Comment: the function asCallback should return me any rejected promise in between as callback to controoler but it doesn't , it always gives what ever I am returning so its hard to detect whether its an rejected or resolved on controller side

Comment: I have updated my question with sample controller side code.

Comment: @Vibhas I cannot reproduce. If a promise rejects, `asCallback` will call `cb` with the error. Are you sure you didn't forget a `return` somewhere?

Comment: No I didnt forgot return but asCallback works as nodejs callback only in case of this.getConnection() all other are just pure promises so even in between if someone gets rejected it is passed as result to controller and appears in results argument rather then in err argument.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure promises"? What exactly is passed as the result, the exception?

Comment: I made silly  mistake I messed up with brackets and added catch at last that's why it was yielding wrong output.I appreciate for you help bergi.